# OKHTTP3 - How to create a directory

Tags: android, http, okhttp

I use OKHTTP3 library to upload files to my http file server.

I found this code to do this and it works fine.

But I also want to just create a new folder without file.

Does anybody know how to create the request?

```
        OkHttpClient client  = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                    String credential = Credentials.basic(username,password);
                    return response.request().newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", credential)
                            .build();
                }
            })
            .build();

        RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("file", file.getName(),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file))
            .addFormDataPart("other_field", "other_field_value")
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(formBody).build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62800062/creating-a-okhttp3-request-body-to-create-a-folder-in-google-drive ?

Comment: I saw it, but not the same thing

Comment: Are you posting to a .php script?

Comment: I don't think you can create a Folder in your remote HTTP server.
What I usually do is in my service on the server I create the directory with a mkdir command or something similar.

Comment: `.addFormDataPart("subdir", "mydirectory")`. Remove the one for the file. Your php script should know what to do for $subdir.

Comment: @blackapps. Thanks, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Well i have no idea what you tried. I dont even know if you use php scripts and if you adapted a script. You are not very informative.

Answer (score 0):

My Http File Server is in default configuration.
I didn't set up any script, because I don't understand the process(see on https://rejetto.com/wiki/index.php?title=HFS:_Event_scripts)

Thank you

Comment: Please use the space dedicated to answers, only for answers :) You can clarify any doubt of the community by making a comment and not an answer. Also, if applicable, you can edit your question.